# Nginx return changes http response header content type from application/pdf to text/html

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I want to redirect from this url:

`localhost:80/files/1.pdf`

to this url:

`localhost:80/viewer.html?pdf=/files/1.pdf`

I am using nginx return to do that:

```
location ~* /files/(.+\.pdf)$ {
    return $scheme://$host:$server_port/viewer.html?pdf=/files/$1;
}
```

viewer.html uses PDF.js and tries to open the pdf given in the urls parameters and log the numbers of its pages:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.3.200/build/pdf.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search; // has the params of the url
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); //parses the params
    const filePath = urlParams.get('pdf');
    var loadpdf = pdfjsLib.getDocument(filePath);

    loadpdf.promise.then(function(document) {
        console.log(document._pdfInfo.numPages);
    }, function (reason) { // PDF loading error
        console.error(reason);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the redirection happens the HTTP GET response header of the pdf has content-type: text/html instead of application/pdf and the pdf can no longer be read.

Is something wrong with nginx return, can somebody point out what it is?

Comment: If you could give us a look at viewer.html?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: It looks as if nginx is correct, you're not downloading a PDF, you get a HTML page allowing you to read the PDF.   Why would you redirect to viewer.html if you want the PDF to be sent to the user?

Comment: I don't want to use the default reader. Do you have any idea why this error occurs?

Comment: But there is no error.

Comment: Did you leave out the main part of viewer.html?   What happens with "loadpdf" ?

Comment: No this is exactly what I want to do, I just want to load the pdf using PDF.js, but I get a lot of errors in the log like this one "Warning: Ignoring invalid character "104" in hex string". I can see in the http ressponse header that my pdf has a content type text/html and not applicartion/pdf and that's why PDF.js cannot read that file. If I comment out the return command in my nginx.conf then PDF.js can load my file correctly ( so I know that PDF.js is not the issue here).

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I added code that prints in the log the number of pages of the pdf if the pdf is loaded correctly or an error message if something is wrong. For me it returns an object that says:  "Invalid PDF structure".

Comment: Perhaps when the javascript requests the pdf document, it also gets the viewer.html in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing important parts of the viewer.html page, and the nginx configuration should prevent redirecting if the request comes from the viewer.  Try this:

nginx config:

```
    location ~* ^/.*\.pdf$ {
            if ( $query_string !~ "noredir" ) {
                    rewrite /(.*\.pdf)$ viewer.html?pdf=$1 redirect;
            }
            try_files $uri =404;
    }
```

viewer.html (adds ?noredir to the filepath):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.3.200/build/pdf.min.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id="the-canvas"></canvas>

<script>
    const queryString = window.location.search; // has the params of the url
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString); //parses the params
    const filePath = urlParams.get('pdf') + "?noredir";
    var loadpdf = pdfjsLib.getDocument(filePath);
    console.log(filePath);

    loadpdf.promise.then(function(pdf) {
          console.log('PDF loaded');

          // Fetch the first page
          var pageNumber = 1;
          pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
            console.log('Page loaded');

            var scale = 1.5;
            var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});

            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
            var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context
            var renderContext = {
              canvasContext: context,
              viewport: viewport
            };
            var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
            renderTask.promise.then(function () {
              console.log('Page rendered');
            });
          });
        }, function (reason) {
          // PDF loading error
          console.error(reason);
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is based upon [pdf.js examples on github](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/)

Comment: I saw your answer only after I figured it out myself! Wow! Still thank you very much !!

Comment: I prefer using return over rewrite since it is said in the documentation that it is simpler. Why did you chose rewrite?

Comment: Old habits die hard, coming from prolonged use of Apache.  And fearful of the "if" caveats.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the redirection was also happening when I was trying to get the pdf itself!

So I added a parameter to the url when we wanted to get the pdf:

```
var loadpdf = pdfjsLib.getDocument(filePath+ "?getFile=true");
```

And changed the nginx.conf to redirect only when I have no other params at the url:

```
location ~* /files/(.+\.pdf)$ {
        if ($is_args = "") { # do the redirect only if you have no parameters in the url
                return $scheme://$host:$server_port/viewer.html?pdf=/files/$1;
        }
    }
```

Thank you @Gerard H. Pille